# Apply custom shipping total during or after order creation via REST API

Tags: magento2

Generating orders via REST is easy -- just like... https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-order/

I need to adjust the transport overall both prior to (quote) or after (Sales order) and then recompute the order totals. This ought to also be performed through the REST API.

So far the best I can find is to manually recalculate everything and update the **Sales Order** via POST to **V1/orders** --

https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/orders#operation/PostV1Orders

Is there no better way to have magento do the Re-calculation?  or to provide the custom shipping total to the quote just before the quote is converted to an Order?